# Correlated Subqueries in BigQuery - How to avoid subqueries with JOIN

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I just want to make a query

```
select *, 
(select --top 1--
fecha_actualizacion from `table` delta2 
where delta2.id=delta.id and delta2.fecha_actualizacion > delta.fecha_actualizacion 
order by delta2.fecha_actualizacion desc) fecha_fin
FROM `table` delta
```

but Bigquery drops de following errors:
-For subquery -> Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.
-for "TOP 1" -> Syntax error: Expected ")" but got integer literal "1" at [2:13]

Any recomendations?

Comment: provide sample data and desired output